# isBeingPresented value is inconsistent

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I present a NavigationController with a ViewController in it modally.

In the ViewController I can see that `self.navigationController.isBeingPresented` is true.

*But* if I now push a new ViewController on the modally presented NavigationController and pop back to the original ViewController the same call to check `isBeingPresented` returns false.

Documentation is sparse but I can't really explain this inconsistency other than that it may be a bug?

Comment: In what method of view controller's lifecycle do you check the `isBeingPresented`?

Comment: In `viewWillAppear`. I got that one.

Answer (score 22):

That's the intended behavior.
`isBeingPresented` is true only when the given `viewController` is currently **being** presented ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2097564-isbeingpresented)):

> A Boolean value indicating whether the view controller is being presented.

and not when it is already presented. It is set to true during the presentation process - from the point when navigation to that view controller starts until the moment when the view controller is fully presented, and all the lifecycle events happened (presentation animations finished, `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` callbacks were called, etc.). After that moment, the view controller **is** presented, but not **is being** presented, thus the `isBeingPresented` will **not** be set to true anymore.

The `self.navigationController` was presented at first (by modal presentation), popping a view controller from it does not trigger a presentation. After presenting a `UINavigationController`, it is presented whole time during pushing and popping view controllers on it. You would have to `dismiss` the `navigationController`, and then present it again for the `isBeingPresented` to be `true` - because only during modal presentation it is being presented.

Comment: If I get it correctly you mean that it is only true during the first presentation event? But the setup is such that the `UINavigationController` stays modally presented during all the pushing/popping within it. Wouldn't it be useful to know that?

Comment: @Alper for the setup you describe, **there is only ONE presentation event**.. the **navigationController is presented the whole time**, no new presentation event happens.. and the viewControllers in it are **pushed**, not presented, so for them `isBeingPresented` won't be set to true, neither

Comment: Like you say because "the navigationController is presented the whole time" I would expect that `isBeingPresented` would be true the whole time.

Comment: @Alper `isBeingPresented` means that it is **being** presented, not that it is presented.. it is in process of being presented - that holds true from the point where you call `present(viewController:)` with it as a parameter till the moment the completion of `present(viewController:)` is called - as soon as the view controller becomes fully presented (animations finished, all the callbacks were called, etc.), it is not `isBeingPresented` anymore - the keyword here is **being**.. it is `true` only during the process of being presented, not showing that it is presented now

Comment: In my case, I was actually presenting the **`navigationController`** (which contains `rootViewController`) -- in `rootViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method, I check for `if let isBeingPresented = navigationController?.isBeingPresented { ... }` and this works.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this property is only true during presentation (note the verb "being" used).

If you are trying to determine if your view controller, or it's navigation controller, is presented, try this instead:

```
if self.navigationController?.presentingViewController != nil {
    // is presented, eg modally
}
```